# Which Style i should use for my iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

Hi i am new to IOS programming. I want to Make a brochure app only read function no user inputs. Which Style i should go for Window based or View Based. I downloaded Xcode it doesn't have Window Based application at has View based only? 
Can you also tell me good tutorials to learn app development

Answer (score 2):

For this type of application you should go for the page-based application see below image

[image]

This provides the basic structure with swipe to change page like books or brochure at the time of reading in real world.

Answer (score 2):

You said that you're new to iOS development; it sounds like you're *very* new to iOS development?

Do you have a developer account?
The freely available documentation on developer.apple.com is very good. It would certainly do no harm to start there. As an example, here are a few of the guides they have on offer:

Start Developing iOS Apps Today
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/Introduction.html

iOS Programming Guide
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072

View Controller Programming Guide for iOS
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457

The developer videos are also very good:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/

You need to sign into your developer account for those...

Play around with a few things. Look at some of the sample code. Write some basic stuff. It might be a good idea to get a bit of momentum before starting on your first app. Spot some of the initial "oh, I see how that works"...

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah Man very new indeed Just Downloaded it yesterday... I am a Web Developer this is gona be my first app :-)

Comment: Oh cool ;) As another suggestion, I have a friend who is just starting to write their first app. He has a web development background too; new to iOS. He's working through the book: "iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide, Third Edition (3rd Edition)".

I haven't used it, so can't comment myself - but he has said that it's pretty good.

Best of luck,
Gavin

Comment: Thank Mate  :-) will surely have a look